# XSLT: recognize if <xsl:copy> did something

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, warnings

I'm tying to convert a normed xml-file into another norm. So theoretically all < elements > and @attributes are known. But there is a slight propability that there are handtyped information in that file which doesn't meet the norm.
I did the following:

### XML-File

```
<tasklist>
   <task1 enabled="true">
      <param>123</param>
   </task1>
   <task2 enabled="true">
      <param>123</param>
   </task2>
   <randomhandwritten>some important information</randomhandwritten>
</tasklist>
```

### XSL-File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:message>Match <xsl:copy-of select="."/> </xsl:message>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="tasklist/task1">
    <xsl:variable name="content" select="param"/>
    <screen enabled="true" param="{$content}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tasklist/task2">
    <xsl:variable name="content" select="param"/>
    <printer enabled="true" param="{$content}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Usually, there would not be any handwritten elements, so all work is done by templates and copy should not do anything. But in the case someone DID write elements in it, is there a way to warn the user of my XSL-File that the copy-method actually did something? 
Otherwise I would apply the same script without the copy-method and compare both of them if they did the same output, but that would be... kinda dirty.

Thanks a lot!
reineke

EDIT:
Thanks for the help with the xsl:message!!
With the shown XSL-File I get an output for

> Match some important information

but also for

> Match
>
> 123
>
> 123
>
> some important information

I cant see why ALL element-contents are shown in one match? can someone show me how to omit the last match, or should i accept it, how it is?

Comment: What exactly do you call "copy-method", that first template?

Comment: Yes. I thought, the first template copies everything, that is there, except other (i.e. more specific) Templates are handling them. And i only want a message, log, or whatever IF it actually did something (and not everything in the XML file was covered by followed templates

Comment: Then you should be able to use `xsl:message` in that template to output a message each time the template is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your XSLT output something besides the result document(s), you can use `<xsl:message>...</xsl:message>` in XSLT 1.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#message and additionally `<xsl:message select="..."/>` in XSLT 2.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#message.

So an `<xsl:template match="node()"><xsl:message>Match on <xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:message>...` or `<xsl:template match="node()"><xsl:message select="concat('Match on ', name())"/>...` would output a message showing the matched node respectively its name.